# Not able to get proper results using Apache Shiro configuration

Tags: java, apache, shiro, security-roles

I am trying to use apache shiro into my project as I have to create a role based mechanism into my project. I created a demo project with following configurations...

I created following files into my project -

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Shiro Web Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a test for Shiro Web Framework</h1>

<a href = "success.jsp">Click Here!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Shiro Web Test : Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<%! String errorMessage = null; %>
<% 
errorMessage = (String) request.getAttribute("shiroLoginFailure");
if (errorMessage != null) { %>
<font color="red">Invalid Login: ${errorMessage}</font><br/>
<font color="black"><h3>Enter login information...</h3></font>
<% } else { %>
<font color="black"><h3>Enter login information...</h3></font>
<% } %>

<form action="loginTest.do" method="POST">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Username:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="rememberMe" />Remember Me?<br />
<input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**success.jsp**
**denied.jsp**
**logout.jsp**
**showUser.jsp**

My **shiro.ini** configuration is as follows -

```
# =======================
# Shiro INI configuration
# =======================

[main]
authc = org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.FormAuthenticationFilter
roles = org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authz.RolesAuthorizationFilter
authc.loginUrl = /login.jsp
authc.failureKeyAttribute = shiroLoginFailure
roles.unauthorizedUrl = /denied.jsp

[users]
admin = password, ROLE_ADMIN
member = password, ROLE_MEMBER

[roles]
ROLE_ADMIN = *

[urls]
/success.jsp = authc, roles[ROLE_MEMBER]
/secret.jsp = roles[ROLE_ADMIN]
```

I am using a servlet **LoginTestServlet.java** to dispatch to **login.jsp** page or **success.jsp** after authentication is successful/unsuccessful -

```
public class LoginTestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        generateResponse(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        generateResponse(request, response);
    }

    protected void generateResponse(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        UserCredentials user = new UserCredentials();
        user.setUserName(request.getParameter("username"));
        user.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));

        if (user.getUserName() != null && user.getPassword() != null) {
            Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro.ini");
            SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();
            SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
            Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();

            UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword());

            try {
                currentUser.login(token);
                Session session = currentUser.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("user", user.getUserName());
            } catch (UnknownAccountException uae) {
                request.setAttribute("shiroLoginFailure", uae.getMessage());
                System.err.println("Exception type: " + uae.getClass().getName());
                System.err.println("Error due to: " + uae.getMessage());
            } catch (IncorrectCredentialsException iae) {
                request.setAttribute("shiroLoginFailure", iae.getMessage());
                System.err.println("Exception type: " + iae.getClass().getName());
                System.err.println("Error due to: " + iae.getMessage());
            } catch (LockedAccountException lae) {
                request.setAttribute("shiroLoginFailure", lae.getMessage());
                System.err.println("Exception type: " + lae.getClass().getName());
                System.err.println("Error due to: " + lae.getMessage());
            } catch (AuthenticationException ae) {
                request.setAttribute("shiroLoginFailure", ae.getMessage());
                System.err.println("Exception type: " + ae.getClass().getName());
                System.err.println("Error due to: " + ae.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                request.setAttribute("shiroLoginFailure", e.getMessage());
                System.err.println("Exception type: " + e.getClass().getName());
                System.err.println("Error due to: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            RequestDispatcher view = null;

            if (currentUser.isAuthenticated() && currentUser.hasRole("ROLE_MEMBER")) {
                view = request.getRequestDispatcher("success.jsp");
                view.forward(request, response);
            } else if (currentUser.isAuthenticated() && currentUser.hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
                view = request.getRequestDispatcher("secret.jsp");
                view.forward(request, response);
            } else {
                view = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
                view.forward(request, response);
            }
        }
    }//end of generateResponse()

}//end of class
```

I am using TOMCAT 6.0.

My problem is -

1. Whenever I am trying to enter credentials at **login.jsp** page, its automatically taking me to the respective page for the credentials I enter. Ex., if I try to enter ROLE_MEMBER credentials after clicking for **success.jsp**, its taking me to **success.jsp** page. But if I try to enter ROLE_ADMIN after clicking for same **success.jsp**, its automatically taking me to **secret.jsp** as per the servlet code written instead of going to **denied.jsp**.
2. How to make a generic code without writing a separate servlet for each resource to show login success or denied page?

Also, is there any way to create custom permissions in shiro for every resource? If yes, then how. If there is any link to this, I would be grateful to you.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wondering why you've decided to handle the authentication inside a servlet rather than [using the pre-built filter](http://shiro.apache.org/web.html#Web-%257B%257Bweb.xml%257D%257D) as is already defined in the guide (among other things, you seem to be reloading the configuration and creating a new `SecurityManager` on every request...). The filter should handle the details in #1 for you.

If you insist on using a servlet, you need to add a value either to the session or as a parameter to the request to login.jsp which tells it where it should redirect the user after successful authentication and read that parameter once the user is authenticated.

Regarding #2, you are simply forwarding `success.jsp` after successful authentication. You aren't either 1) explicitly checking the user's roles or allowing the framework to do so for you. Again, switching to the filter should resolve this for you.

Comment: I am trying to understand what you are saying. Okay, I will and want to use the built-in shiro filter only, but in that case, what should be the action attribute in login.jsp, or how this will be done? I am trying to figure it out... As later on, I have to use JDBC realm to do so...

Comment: Okay... I got it. I kept the action = "" in form tag in login.jsp, and it worked like magic. In this case, I don't need to take care of where to check what. Thanks for the help. It was easy. Anyways, will get back to you for other questions as well... thanks a lot.

Comment: I am a little bit confused with shiro. The configuration which worked in a small test project, did not worked on a development project. It was too inconsistent. Putting action="" in the for authentication filter sometimes worked, and sometimes didn't. And even using basic authentication filter, its not working now.

Comment: @Vishal: I can't really diagnose to much without seeing the configs. What strikes me as being possible, though, is that the URL pattern for your filter might not be matching all of the requests. I think the pattern recommended in the Shiro examples is `/*`, which should act on any request.